# Where to run node.js

Tags: node.js

So I thought about giving node.js a try seeing the possibilities it has for a little test chat project (with mysql) I'm doing.

But what I couldn't find out is where to run the file from and whats most common.

What I currently have:

- A FreeBSD server with latest Node and PHP 5.3.x
- A vhost
- some tutorials on how to start with node (which I looked through and got exited about)
- knowledge on how to run it from terminal without having to keep my terminal open (screen)

So far so good.

What I need:

- Some basic information of where to put the (lets say:) chat.js file.
- Most logical port to run it on

So the web root (www) runs on a user (not root obviously). And the webroot has an underlying folder where I could put the script (away from visitors grabby little hands). This seems to me to be the most safe place to put it seeing nobody can get to it, which is probably what I want seeing I'm going to connect to a db and don't want my DB login data out there (I don't know how this works yet but I'll figure out db connect with node later, no answer required).

But if a file is not in the webroot, it seems to me a connection cannot be made from outside. Cause my webroot is configured to only allow 80 (or ssl on 443) incomming traffic, which is logical. Outgoing obviously has no problems.

All the examples that I found don't really help me. They just do everything on a local machine, which sucks for me cause I don't want to do that.

So what I would like to is the best practice for:

- Where to put the file
- port to run it on.

Comment: Node isn't like PHP.  You don't need apache, or a vhost.  It doesn't go into a webroot.  Node is more like python - it is it's own entirely separate executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What is Node.js?](http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs)

A lot of the confusion for newcomers to Node is misunderstanding exactly what it is. The description on nodejs.org definitely doesn't help.

An important thing to realize is that Node is not a webserver. By itself it doesn't do anything. It doesn't work like Apache. There is no config file where you point it to you HTML files. If you want it to be a HTTP server, you have to write an HTTP server (with the help of its built-in libraries). Node.js is just another way to execute code on your computer. It is simply a JavaScript runtime.

A nice tutorial [How to Deploy Node JS Applications, With Examples](https://gun.io/blog/tutorial-deploy-node-js-server-with-example/)

> You'll need to have your non-node application on port 9000 (for
>   Apache, this will be in /etc/apache2/ports.conf and in your
>   sites-available file for your site), and you'll need your node
>   application to listen on 8080. You'll also need to set up DNS 'A'
>   records for the different hostnames you'll be using for your servers.

Companies like Heroku allow for automated deployment of apps from the desktop to the cloud. 
Nodejitsu provides a tool called jitsu that makes deploying an Node.js application super simple. You can install jitsu with npm.

```
npm install jitsu -g
```

[Heroku How To](http://scripting.com/2014/02/06/herokuForPoetsBeta.html)
[Getting started with jitsu](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs)

Use monit, forever, upstart or systemd to start your node server. Use Varnish or HAProxy or Nginx (Nginx not work with websockets).

Comment: [Deploying a Node.js app to IBM BlueMix](http://joelennon.com/deploying-a-node-js-app-to-ibm-bluemix/)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you can stick it anywhere you want.  I recommend running your application using Forever or similar instead of directly with Node.  I usually keep my apps in /var/ and let each one run under a unique user.  I do not recommend keeping them in your http root, as your .js files are should NOT be interpreted by Apache, php, etc.

To be clear - you do NOT need a traditional webserver, nor do you need php,mySQL or anything else.  Node is all you need.  It'll serve content directly - it IS the webserver.

Often times you'll have each app use a high port number (3000+) and use NGINX to proxy them all to different hostnames off of port 80 (allowing you to easily have multiple apps on a single machine).  If you aren't using some sort of proxy, then 3000 is very default, but there is no correct or incorrect port, so long as you don't use a reserved port.

Comment: So to break it down: 
- I do NOT put it in the webroot (but the one above that is not controlled by apache is fine). 
- I checked out Forever, it seems similar to screen, so both will do. - Nginx is not a necessity if you do not have a lot of users. - 3000 will do just fine. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct in regards to Apache.  Forever, unlike screen, will restart your app if it crashes.  Yes, 3000 is fine.